# How to make an openshift Django app work locally as well, so I can test befor push it to production?

Tags: django, localhost, openshift

I created a Django app on Openshift, after all the configurations it is now working properly on the server. I have the files pulled to my desktop using git, but it does not work to call `django-admin runserver`. Is there any way to make it work locally as well?

Comment: Did you use the django template from openshift or your own? Please post some code and what errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Using `manage.py runserver` instead of `django-admin runserver` might save you some [troubles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/).
All your settings should be in `settings.py` file.
Then add this at top of a `settings.py` file:

```
import os

# a setting to determine whether we are running on OpenShift
DEBUG = True
ON_OPENSHIFT = False
if os.environ.has_key('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'):
    ON_OPENSHIFT = True
    DEBUG = False
```

And then change settings for localhost and openshift as you need, for example database:

```
DATABASES = {}
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL'))
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'],
        'USER': url.username,
        'PASSWORD': url.password,
        'HOST': url.hostname,
        'PORT': url.port,
        }
else:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'appname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',
        }
```

Or use `if not DEBUG` instead of `if ON_OPENSHIFT`.